# Mouse focus stuck (Linux)

Tags: linux, mouse, mouse-click, window-focus

1. Sorry for crappy post layout, posting from my phone.
2. Problem: mouse focus gets stuck. Not sure how to explain it, I can sometimes get it to switch to a window, but once there it's locked until that window closes (usually alt+f4)  when focus locks, alt-tab becomes unavailable aswell. 
   When focus becomes locked, mouse clicks seem to be completly ignored, except for the purpose of re-locking on a new window.

Running Fedora 20 with mate-compiz. Have tried disabling compiz, no effect. Mouse works fine on other Fedora 20 PC and in Windows on same PC as one having problem, so can rule out hardware.

I have no clue what happened to cause this, was working fine before I left for work, came home, problem appeared. Didn't even go through a shutdown between when I left and came back. Have rebooted, no effect. Tried noapic and acpi=off no effect. When using xev, no mouse clicks register.

Please help Dx

Comment: I have the same behavior on Gnome3 for debian (wheezy) & Ubuntu 14 right after installing them from an USB key (or even during the installation process...). Have you found anything worth trying?

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing similar issue too, yet have not found a fix for it, only a workaround.

The best work-around I found for (my problem) it, after some experimentation, is to use the 'Windows Special Key' to move the application in question around a little bit, and mouse /should/ be released. At least this has been working for me when it happens. Not ideal, but a quick alt-drag (my windows key is alt, you can set this in 'System Settings -> Windows -> Moving and Resizing Windows') does do it for me...

Best of luck!